Movie with a secret party in a forest
This film is not a horror film. Watched it recently so must be after 2000 (can't be sure. Just guesswork). Most probably it was a comedy and the language of the movie was English.
In it, a group of friends go to a forest  as a challenge (or some similar reason).
One of them goes missing and the remaining friends start searching for him when they hear weird noises. They think it's some animal in the woods, and try to escape/run here and there but it's actually a guy from the secret party (he was wearing a hoodie and has his face covered at first. Seeing that the friends are terrified, but then he lifts his hoodie off and tells them he's here enjoying the party and invites the other remaining friends too, to a secret party that's going on in the forest)
They accept that and when they go to the party, they find that the friend who went missing is already there at the party (so he actually didn't go missing, he discovered the party from the sounds and joined them)  I cannot recollect anything else about the plot.

Hi. Do you remember the film's year? Country? Its general plot? Was it a comedy?

I have no idea which year it was. But watched it recently so must be after 2000 (can't be sure. Just guesswork) But yeah most probably it was a comedy and the language of the movie was English. I'm really sorry but I cannot recollect anything else about the plot.

Is it "scouts guide to zombie apocalypse", There will be similar scene with 3 friends go to forest for a camp, 1 guy will be missing, they will hear something in the woods,..


This doesn't quite sound like the plot you described but The Hole fits the keywords group of friends, forest, challenge and party which lead to the IMDB Synopsis so it could be this movie.
Sorry but this is seriously the only movie I could think of with your description.

I watched The Hole recently on Netflix and it definitely does not fit the description in the question. But I did enjoy it, I would say it was worth watching. Nice try though!

No I checked up on it and it definitely isn't The Hole. Actually the problem is that this description provided by me isn't the main plot of the movie. It's just a scene for around 5-10 minutes so it's hard for you'll to guess correctly or for me to recollect! :'(
